# How to insert data entry table into data warehouse?

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database, data-warehouse, ms-access-2016

I am constructing a database application in Access 2016 for a dog kennel. The kennel must be able to track which dogs are put in which cages, with what other dogs, on any given day.

I have a central table `TEST_DAYCARE`, which is acting as the hub of the data warehouse, and its fields are derived from the tables: `TEST_RUN` (cages), `t_Dogs_COPY` (Dogs that go to the kennel), and `TEST_EMPLOYEE` (employees of the business).

There will be a form that users will interface with to populate the database on a daily basis, which will flush all necessary data into `TEST_DAYCARE`. `t_Temp_Dogs` will be the data entry table and will appear on the form.

I'm stuck on moving the `str_dog` (dog name) and `str_lname` (dog last name) from `t_TEMP_dogs` to `TEST_DAYCARE` using an `INSERT INTO` query.

I'm trying to automate things as much as possible, and have another `INSERT INTO IF NOT EXISTS` query that inserts new dog names (first and last) into the `t_Dogs_COPY` table if the unique combination is not already there. I am having trouble referencing that new entry in the `t_TEMP_dogs`table so it can be flushed to `TEST_DAYCARE`

Schema is below.

Red arrow = Data Entry Table.

Blue Arrow = Dog Names table

Any thoughts? Is there an easier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Easier way is to not replicate dog names in multiple tables, just save ID. Use form/subform arrangement for data entry. Use comboboxes for data entry. Use combobox NotInList event to enter new lookup record "on the fly" during data entry. Why use TEST/TEMP/COPY in table names? Suggest names be what you would want in deployed database.

Comment: Not clear to me the purpose of t_TEMP_dogs instead of data entry directly into TEST_DAYCARE. Not even showing fields in TEST_DAYCARE for str_dog and str_lname. Advise not to use all upper case in naming - it's harder to read.

Comment: Thank you— yeah these naming conventions suck. This is a mock-up of the final schema, which I’m working the kinks out with these set of test tables which are messy. 

I wanted to use t_TEMP_dogs as a catch-all for data entry, so the person entering data would be able to easily keep track of the dogs that were already recorded without having to flip back. 

Pardon my ignorance, but can a form display all that information at once while new data is being entered?

Comment: Why would they 'flip back' - form is in Single view? Form can be in Continuous or Datasheet view.

Comment: It's not necessarily the naming conventions that will cause problems for you later but that your schema looks like it's going to turn out not to be properly normalized. Your current problem is probably just an early example of the challenges you'll encounter without a normalized database.

Comment: stifin-- could you elaborate on that? I can see what you mean if you're talking about the t_TEMP_Dogs table off to the right, but to my understanding the rest is normalized. Is this the case?

Comment: to be more accurate, BOTH structure and names that IMO should be improved. In no particular order: 1) tables are better named after their logical entities if they have a corresponding logical entity e.g. why "TEST_RUN" when it means "cages"? 2) Why "TEST", "TEMP", "COPY" at all? 3) As noted before, use ID_dog instead of storing redundant str_dog, etc (doesn't even meet 3NF) 4) EMPLOYEE AND EMPLOYEE_1 dead giveaway of non-normalization i.e. an employee is just an employee - there should not be 2 tables for this... And running out of chars so need to end :)

Comment: let me add more about naming conventions: column names should not be named after their data types i.e. "str_" is not recommended. Just to check my own opinion, I searched on database naming conventions and came across this: "Beware of numbers in any object names, especially table names. It normally flags up clumsy denormalization where data is embedded in the name, as in ‘Year2017’, ‘Year2018’ etc. Usually the significance of the numbers is obvious to the perpetrator, but not to the maintainers of the system." https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/sql-naming-conventions/

Comment: @stifin, there are not two tables for Employees, it is the same table pulled into Relationships builder twice. For some reason, two employees are associated with each DAYCARE record. This is not strict normalization but might be adequate in this case. "Normalize until hurts, denormalize until it works."

Comment: One employees table is good :) Denormalization with redundant columns is sometimes used in 50- or 100-table DBs to help things like avoiding 5-table joins. The standard is 3NF, especially for small DBs with less than a dozen tables. Regarding your original question, the first comment about not duplicating dog details is the best. However, if you really want an INSERT INTO if not exists, my answer to here has a query very similar to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506488/microsoft-access-merging-multiple-tables-with-same-fields?noredirect=1#comment117572424_66506488